# drupal 7 website spammed with redirect

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, redirect

appearing sometimes, all my website's URL redirect to spam URL.
I guess a javascript file do this.

I don't know where to find and what solution could be the best to find or at least block those redirect

Thanks

Comment: Add more information, There is no where near enough information for people to give you a good answer.
But, first thing would be to make sure your Drupal installation is up to date, if not, pray that is has not been affected by any of the drupalgeddon vulnerabilities.

Comment: Is your website public? Can you give us the link?

Answer (score 2):

You have to find if :

- it's a php redirect : disable the "redirect" module and check if the problem is always here
- it's a JS custom block for instance that has been hacked, or a module allowing you to write Php code from Drupal admin

Your Drupal is maybe hacked, see here for more informations : https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-drupal

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I just solved the problem, it was a JS infection.